Convert webpack.config.js to vite
I'm trying to migrate my react app from webpack to vite
Here's my webpack config file :
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const DotenvWebpackPlugin = require("dotenv-webpack");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const urlDev = "localhost:3000/";

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const prod = options.mode === "production";
  const config = {
    cache: false,
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      loginfile: "./src/login/loginfile.ts",
      logoutfile: "./src/logout/logoutfile.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
      publicPath: "/",
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new DotenvWebpackPlugin({ path: `.env.${options.mode}` }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "loginfile.html",
        template: "./src/login/loginfile.html",
        chunks: ["loginfile"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "redirect.html",
        template: "./src/redirectPage/redirect.html",
        chunks: ["redirect"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "logoutfile.html",
        template: "./src/logout/logoutfile.html",
        chunks: ["logoutfile"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "endlogout.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/endlogout.html",
        chunks: ["login", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "privacy.html",
        template: "./src/privacy.html",
        chunks: ["privacy"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      https: await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};

I have installed vite and created vite config file
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import reactRefresh from "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh";
import { resolve } from "path";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import html from "rollup-plugin-html";
import dotenv from "rollup-plugin-dotenv";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

// Define HTTPS options
// Note: Vite does not support custom HTTPS options out of the box. You may need to use a reverse proxy for this.

// Define config
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const isDev = mode === "development";
  const isProd = mode === "production";

  return {
    plugins: [
      reactRefresh(),
      copy({
        targets: [
          { src: "assets/*", dest: "dist/assets" },
          { src: "manifest*.xml", dest: "dist" },
        ],
        hook: "writeBundle", // notice here
      }),
      html({
        include: "**/*.html",
        htmlMinifierOptions: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
        },
      }),
      dotenv({ path: `.env.${mode}` }),
      isProd && terser(),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      },
    },
    css: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: autoprefixer({}),
      },
    },
    server: {
      host: true,
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
      strictPort: true,
      hmr: {
        overlay: false,
      },
    },
    build: {
      outDir: "dist",
      emptyOutDir: true,
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  };
});

after running the app , it's compiling but when I go to localhost:3000 nothing happens .
I think that there is an issue in the config
